# How to achieve `git rm --cached` and `git rm -f`with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

1) I tried using `repo.Index.Remove(item.Filename);`, but it's giving me:

> Additional information: Unable to remove file 'file.txt'. Its current
>   status is 'Modified'.

I need to find a way to do `git rm file.txt -f` (i.e. force removal).

2) I need a way to do `git rm file.txt --cached` so that the file is only removed from the repository (staged for removal), but still keeping it in the filesystem. Is there a way to do this in LibGit2Sharp?

3) Is it OK to call `repo.Index.Remove()` if the given path has never been part of the repository (i.e. the file is untracked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find a way to do git rm file.txt -f (i.e. force removal).

There's no built-in way to do this. Might be worth opening a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues).

> I need a way to do git rm file.txt --cached

Although the content check won't be performed, I think `repo.Index.Unstage()` should fit your need.
The documentation of the method states *Removes from the staging area all the modifications of a file since the latest commit (addition, updation or removal).*

> Is it OK to call repo.Index.Remove() if the given path has never been part of the repository (i.e. the file is untracked)?

No, it's not ;) Similarly to git, LibGit2Sharp will throw if one is trying to Remove a file with one of the following status:

- FileStatus.Nonexistent
- FileStatus.Removed
- FileStatus.Modified
- FileStatus.Untracked

Description of what those status mean can be found **[here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/FileStatus.cs#L9)**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will do for `git rm -f`:

```
File.Delete(RepositoryFullPath + "/" + item.Filename);

if (!item.Status.HasFlag(LibGit2Sharp.FileStatus.Untracked))
{
    repo.Index.Stage(RepositoryFullPath + "/" + item.Filename);
}
```

I don't know how to do `--cached` yet.